# Bad state: Stream has already been listened to Flutter error

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I am calling an api. I am getting a  streamed response after sending the request. But i cannot parse the response and convert it to String/JSON. This is where I am calling the api.

```
static Future<String> callDeviceListFetchApi() async {
Completer completer = new Completer();
String jsonResponse;
String url = Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.DEVICE_REGISTER_URL;
var client = new http.Client();
var request = new http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
request.headers[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE] = 'application/json';
request.headers[HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION] = '<auth code>';
await client.send(request).then((response) {
  response.stream.bytesToString().then((value) {
    print(value.toString());
    jsonResponse = value.toString();
    completer.complete(jsonResponse);
  });
}).catchError((error) {
  print(error.toString());
});
return completer.future;
}
```

I am getting the error,
`Bad state: Stream has already been listened to` Flutter error. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What line does the stack trace point to? Is the method called more then once to cause this error?

Comment: I think `response.stream.bytesToString().then((value) ` this is the line causing the issue. Also I am getting the error only while debugging. Running the application otherwise doesn't show any error. I am a bit confused.

Comment: You don't have any watches in the debugger window that could interfere?

Comment: BTW I don't know if that auth code you had in your code example is the one you actually use, but I'd *HIGHLY* recommend not posting it on the internet =D

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things wrong with your code. I think you have a slight misunderstanding about how Async and Futures work in dart - you should re-read the [docs](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures) and this tutorial ([part 1](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async) and [part 2](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/beyond-async)).

Basically, the problem is that you were returning a 'Future' from an async function. If you return a future from an async function, it has issues (I don't know why the analyzer doesn't catch that).

```
Future<String> callDeviceListFetchApi() async {
  Completer completer = new Completer();
  String url = "<url>";
  var client = new http.Client();
  var request = new http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE] = 'application/json';
  request.headers[HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION] =
      '<auth string>';
  var response = await client.send(request);
  String jsonResponse;
  try {
    var value = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    print(value.toString());
    jsonResponse = value.toString();
  } catch (error) {
    print(error.toString());
  }
  return completer.complete(jsonResponse);
}
```

Or not async:

```
Future<String> callDeviceListFetchApiNotAsync() {
  String url = "<url>";
  var client = new http.Client();
  var request = new http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE] = 'application/json';
  request.headers[HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION] =
      '<auth string>';
  Completer completer = new Completer();

  return client.send(request).then((response) {
    return response.stream.bytesToString();
  }).then((value) {
    print(value.toString());
    return value.toString();
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error.toString());
    // if you use catchError, whatever you return from it
    // is the value you'll get wherever you resolve the future.
    return null;
  });
}
```

But unless you're trying to do something I'm not seeing, there's a way easier way to do this (assuming all you want to do is get a string from a server):

```
Future<String> getList() async {
  var response = await http.get("<url>", headers: {
    HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json', 
    HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: '<auth string>',
  });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return response.body;
  } else {
    throw Error();
  }
}
```