# StreamBuilder. Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter

I have StreamBuilder

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    initialData: false,
    stream: widget.stream, ...
```

For initializing widget I call:

```
_EventSpeakerPager(..., streamController.stream.distinct());
```

And this produce error "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to."
Without `distinct()` it works, but it's not suitable for me.

I've tried `asBroadcastStream()` and got the same error

Does anybody know, how can I handle this

P.S. I've already looked into these:

[topic1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396769/flutter-bad-state-stream-has-already-been-listened-to), [topic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447356/bad-state-stream-has-already-been-listened-to-flutter-error), [topic3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49764061/flutter-nested-streambuilders-causing-bad-state-stream-has-already-been-listene) - nothing helps

P.P.S.
When I use stream without `StreamBuilder` - all works fine

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
widget.stream.listen((bool data) {
  setState(() {
    ...
  });
});
```

}

Comment: Use a `StreamController.broadcast` instead

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So, all I've needed to do is replace

`final StreamController<bool> streamController = StreamController<bool>();`

with `final StreamController<bool> streamController = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();`

Answer (score 10):

Use the `rx_dart` library from pubspec: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart

Now change your `Stream<Something>` declaration to be a `BehaviorSubject<Something>`.
(The BehaviorSubject is a kind of stream that has memory of the last value transmited. There is other subjects available on the library like the `PublishSubject` and the `ReplaySubject`, check their docs for your use case).

The `rx_dart` library is an extension of the Stream base classes and are much more powerful and easier to work.

Check their GitHub: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart

Comment: I don't need rx - as I wrote above - I can do it without StreamBuilder and it works totally fine. I don't want to add additional dependencies. Just trying to figure out and solve this.

Comment: As I said, rx_dart is an extension to the default Stream dart objects. RX_dart fixes some issues that the stream classes has. One of the them is the "broadcast-type" for streams.

Comment: @DanielOliveira Is it really important to use rxDart? i have the same problem and .broadcast() fixes the problem. `RX_dart fixes some issues that the stream classes has` Stream class has bugs? should i use Rxdart?

Comment: When I said "issues" I was refering to "missing of features". It is built over the standard Stream classes (and they work really well)

Comment: I tried `StreamController.broadcast()`, but I had so many problem! After switching to rx_dart my life is much better :) Thanks guys for the tip!